# Repeated Manual Slideshows in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, manual

I'm working on a portfolio site that has multiple manual slideshows on a single page that will loop back to the first image. My existing code works with a single slideshow/set of images. I am having difficulty with how to introduce additional slideshows/image sets without repeating code. I tried to make an array for each image set. My thought was to pass from HTML to JS the specific array to be used. But I'm not sure how to indicate the desired array in JS. I am totally new to Javascript, and am fairly familiar with Python. Passing values to functions between HTML and JS has been a bit confusing for me at times.

HTML:

```
    <nav id="nav_bar">
<a href="JavaScript:slideshowBack()">PREV</a>
<span>/</span>
<a href="JavaScript:slideshowUp()">NEXT</a>
</nav> 
</header>
<figure id="image">
<img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v486/TimClark123456789/344ca6b8-9f67-4fc9-a745-731870d4f6f2_zps9e1f364a.jpg" name="mypic" border=0>
```

Javascript:

```
var num=1
img1 = new Image ()
img1.src = "http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v486/TimClark123456789/344ca6b8-9f67-4fc9-a745-731870d4f6f2_zps9e1f364a.jpg"
img2 = new Image ()
img2.src = "IMG_7431.jpg" 
img3 = new Image ()
img3.src = "IMG_7396.jpg"
img4 = new Image ()
img4.src = "img_4.jpg" 
img5 = new Image () 
img5.src = "img_6.jpg"
img6 = new Image ()
img6.src = "img_7.jpg"

function slideshowUp()
{
num=num+1
if (num==7)
{num=1}
document.mypic.src=eval("img"+num+".src")
}

function slideshowBack()
{
num=num-1
if (num==0)
{num=6}
document.mypic.src=eval("img"+num+".src")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? You'll find plenty of very well built, battle tested javascript carousels out there that will solve the issue you're worrying about, and probably a bunch down the line. A great example would be Filiament Group's https://github.com/filamentgroup/responsive-carousel

If you must write your own, you can do something like this to optimize the code above:

```
var imageArray = [
  'img/src/example.jpg', 
  'image/src/example2.jpg'
  // and so on, not forgetting commas between each, but not after the last one!
  ];
var images = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = imageArray[i]
}
```

And now you're reusing code. You could create an different images array for each of your different carousels. You could also make your advance commands point towards specific carousels by making them take arguments.